# Can't lookup ENS name on testnet of an address

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js

I'm trying to create an app that works with ENS. I tried registering a test domain on Georli network. Here's the link when I lookup that test domain on app.ens.domains.

https://app.ens.domains/name/rikikudo6.test/details

I try using `ethers` to resolve ens domain as well as looking up a specific address. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var ethers = require("ethers");
// I use rpc endpoint generated by alchemy on Georli network
var provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpc);

(async () => {
    var address = await provider.resolveName("rikikudo6.test");
    console.log("address :>> ", address);

    const ens = await provider.lookupAddress(address);
    console.log("ens :>> ", ens);
})();
```

And here's the result when I run the above script:

```
address :>>  0x8A2D9D8e54FF47d28Cc35Aa2ba244d49F14944cA
ens :>>  null
```

I don't understand why it can resolve the name for `rikikudo6.test` but can't lookup ens for the address returned by the resolving function. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You may have better chance of getting an answer over at the [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) portal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The lookupAddress only returns the ENS name which is set to the default ENS name of user. If the user doesn't have the default ENS name, it will return null.